# Buttons in iOS App won't show

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

I am creating an iPhone app, and I'm having some trouble with the `TableView` and adding buttons. I started with a regular view, and then added a table view, and then a couple buttons to the top, as shown here:

[image: TableViewImage]

The problem is that when I run the app I get this:

[image]

Neither of the buttons that I added are there. Here is my .h file:

```
    //
//  RootBeerTVCViewController.h
//  BaseApp
//
//  Created by Blaine Anderson on 10/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 UIEvolution, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootBeerTVCViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nameButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *locationButton;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* rootList; 



-(IBAction)sort:(id)sender;

@end
```

And here is the .M file:

```
//
//  RootBeerTVCViewController.m
//  BaseApp
//
//  Created by Blaine Anderson on 10/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 UIEvolution, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootBeerTVCViewController.h"
#import "GlobalData.h"

@interface RootBeerTVCViewController ()


@end

@implementation RootBeerTVCViewController
@synthesize rootList; 

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization


    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [GlobalData sharedData].mViewManager.mNavController.navigationBarHidden=NO;

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    rootList = [[GlobalData sharedData] mRootList ];
     NSLog(@"RootList in view did load: %@", rootList);
    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    tableView.delegate = self;

    tableView.dataSource = self;

    //[tableView addSubview:sortingView]; 

    [tableView reloadData];

    self.view = tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    [self setLocationButton:nil];
    [self setNameButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    rootList = [[GlobalData sharedData] mRootList ];
    NSLog(@"RootList: %@", rootList);
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"RootList count: %i", rootList.count);
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"RootList row count: %i", rootList.count);
    return rootList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    rootList =[[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeerParser rootBeerList];
    NSLog(@"RootList Cell: %@", rootList);
    RootBeers* mRootBeer = [rootList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; 
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    NSLog(@"Cell Name: %@", mRootBeer.brewer);
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = mRootBeer.name; 
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = mRootBeer.location; 



    return cell;
}

/*
 // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support editing the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
 // Delete the row from the data source
 [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
 }   
 else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
 // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
 }   
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support rearranging the table view.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
 {
 }
 */

/*
 // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
 - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
 return YES;
 }
 */

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    RootBeers* mRootBeer =[rootList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
    [GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeer = mRootBeer; 
    [[GlobalData sharedData].mViewManager pushView:DETAILVIEW animated:YES]; 



}

- (IBAction)sort:(id)sender {

    rootList =[[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeerParser rootBeerList];


    [[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeerParser sortRootBeerByName:rootList]; 
}
@end
```

If someone could give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong, that would be great. I hope that I have provided enough information, if not, please let me know and I'll be happy to supply more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `viewDidLoad` you create a new `UITableView` of screen size and then set it as VC view, thus overriding the view that was loaded from xib. As a result you are only seeing the table you created in code.